# Get state of activity (paused / resumed)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a LoaderManager to get some data and when it finishes a child fragment should be shown. In some cases this happens when the activity is already in paused state and can not perform the fragment transaction.

Is there a way to get the current state of the activity (seems to have a mResume flag)? Or do I have to maintain my own boolean?

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to maintain your own boolean flag as all of the framework code for this is of a non-public type.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The new Architecture Components allow you to do it with:

```
this.getLifecycle().getCurrentState()
```

Comment: This can be used in an AppCompatActivity, otherwise the Activity needs to implement LifecycleOwner see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle

Answer (score 5):

A quick look in the Activity [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.isResumed%28%29) indicates that the Activity class does keep track on the resume state with the member **mResumed**. But since **mResume** is not public and **isResumed()** is hidden, we can't use them.

You can have a simple solution to provide you with that information for all your classes. Simply create a base Activity class that store the state. For example:

```
public class ActivityBase extends Activity {

    private boolean mIsResumed = false;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mIsResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
        super.onPaused()
        mIsResumed = false;
    }

    public boolean isResumed() {
        return mIsResumed
    }

}
```

Simply extend this class with your class:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActivityBase {

    private void onLoadDone() {
        if (isResumed()) {
            // Show the fragment
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Added some explanations and references. Unfortunately, there is not a built in get for the activity state.

Comment: If there is such a member data/method to get the state, the problem is the Activity may not be accessible or get destroyed, like during app exit. So there is a timing problem to handle. This is an issue in the Android framework.

Comment: Not sure I understand what is this issue you are referring to, but since all the activity life cycle functions are running on the UI thread - there is no race condition / timing problem.

Comment: I would not have a problem, if the activity would actually be destroyed, then the code in onLoaderFinished would not run. The check would be within the activity. isFinishing() does not help, as it is only paused.

Comment: @Eyal, I meant Google statements like "If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity from memory..." makes it hard to query the state from the Activity. I think that can cause a race condition.

Answer (score 5):

One way it could be achieved is by using **breakpoints** on your `Activity` (for instance, putting a breakpoint in your `onResume` method), and using the **Evaluate Expression window** that you can open by clicking a right click on your **Debug menu window**, and selecting it from there (OR SHIFT + F8) for mac. Once opened, you can intercept the current state (depending where your breakpoint is) using this line in your Evaluate Expression Window:

```
getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
```

If it returns `true`, that means your `Activity` is currently in the **resume** **state**. 
If `false`, it's in another state.

They have plenty of other states you can play with, just check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State)